# How to set different java versions for different apps. on a windows PC?

Tags: java, jnlp, multiple-versions

I have 2 different apps, one of them is a `java desktop app` and the other one is a `c# web app`. which uses `java applet` in order to e-sign. The problem is `desktop java app requires 1.5.0_14 and on the other hand web app. requires 1.7` and higher version of java.

I installed both `java 1.5` and `1.7` versions on my PC. In order to run desktop java app., I go to `C:\Progra~2\Java\jre1.5.0_14\bin` and run `javacpl` to **disable 1.7 and enable 1.5**. Then I make a shortcut to `javaws 1.5.0_14` to my desktop and add the jnlp of this java app (`http://abc/appclient/tt.jnlp`) to the target of javaws shortcut. After those settings, the java desktop app. runs.

Now I needed to also run the web app which requires **1.7 java.** In order to run this app. properly **Java 1.5 should be disabled, 1.7 enabled on the Java Control Panel settings**. **Problem is when you run this web app. the settings for 1.5.0_14 break down,** I mean **all of the java versions become enabled in javacpl under `C:\Progra~2\Java\jre1.5.0_14\bin directory`**. If I restart my PC, I need to reset the java versions. **Is there a way to make this happen without pain in the head**?

I would be so glad if you can help me.

By the way, **I tried to use batch files, etc. but did not succeed**. Is there a permanent solution?

**UPDATED:**
Here is how I did it back then.

Here is what I do to solve my issue;

```
    Uninstall the older Java -if there is- (in my case it is 1.5.0_14 )
    install java equal/higher than 1.7 just to run e-sign on my web application

    I prepared a VBScript in order to just run the desired jre version as follows and put jre1.5.0_14, jnlp file and VBScript on the same folder and make shortcut to the VBScript to run.

    Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WSCript.shell") oShell.run "%comspec% /c D:\TMS\jre1.5.0_14\bin\javaws.exe D:\TMS\tt.jnlp -verbose", 1, True

Set oShell = Nothing
```

Best Regards.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For your client ("desktop") application you don't really need a Java 1.5 runtime "installed" - you can just copy/paste for example a JDK installation folder somewhere and otherwise completely uninstall it such that it disappears from any control panel and registry - and then boot the desktop application directly using the javaw.exe executable of the Java 5 JDK you copy/pasted somewhere.

Comment: Java applications can use the java.exe/javaw from any installed Java directory. So a batch file should have worked. You could for instance install Java 8 on some PC, copy its directory to the target computer, and use that java to start a pure java 8 app.

Comment: Hi Gimby, thanks for your comment. I will definetly try and let you know.

Comment: Hello Joop Eggen, so what you trying to say is I do NOT need to install 1.5 on my PC? Just copy the specific java folder on the PC and install 1.7 to run properly?

Comment: *"desktop java app requires 1.5.0_14"*  I Actually thought Oracle had dropped support for using an earlier version of Java, and especially one that is obsolete and might contain known security bugs.  Try running the `1.5.0_14` app. in a modern JRE and see what breaks..

Comment: Hi Gimby, I tried to uninstall jre 1.5 but somehow it still remains under Java Control Panel settings. How can I totally get rid of this jre 1.5?

Comment: @Gimby, I installed jre1.7 than jre1.5 and copy this folder somewhere. Than I uninstalled this jre1.5 but in java control panel it displays the copied jre1.5 folder. How can I fix this?

Comment: I have no idea, I don't know what you exactly did and I am not an Oracle support employee.

Comment: Here is the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382032/how-to-force-to-open-jnlp-file-in-java-1-5-0-14-jre-instead-of-jre-1-7