# How to force to open JNLP File in Java 1.5.0_14 JRE instead of JRE 1.7

Tags: java, windows, jnlp

I have Java 5-based Java Web Start application which I need to open on a Windows PC. PC has JRE 1.7 installed, with JRE 1.5.0_14 copied manually to the another drive (d:). The problem is that whenever I want to open the JW Start application, it opens using Java 7. Even if I use the javaws executable from JRE 1.5.0_14, somehow  some properties still refer to JRE 7 files. How can I force JRE 1.5.0_14 to run just for this application?

Thanks in advance & Best Regards.

**Edit 1:** By the way, I forgot to mention that I need to use java 1.7 for my another app. in order to use e-sign app.

**Edit 2:** The JNLP file has alredy this code inside **`<j2se java-vm-args="-XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xmx512m" version="1.5"/>`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I do to solve my issue;

1. Uninstall the older Java -if there is- (in my case it is 1.5.0_14 )
2. install java equal/higher than 1.7 just to run e-sign on my web application
3. I prepared a VBScript in order to just run the desired jre version as follows and put jre1.5.0_14, jnlp file and VBScript on the same folder and make shortcut to the VBScript to run.

   Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WSCript.shell")
   oShell.run "%comspec% /c D:\TMS\jre1.5.0_14\bin\javaws.exe D:\TMS\tt.jnlp -verbose", 1, True

Set oShell = Nothing

Thats it :)

Answer (score 2):

Include this section in the JNLP file:

```
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.5.0_14">
  </resources>
```

Comment: Hi @JuanZe, thanks for your reply. I am new to Java so would you please tell me how to do that? **Because this Java Web Start app. is NOT under my control. Lets say it's legacy app.**

Comment: Save the JNLP file to your PC, open it with a text editor (like Notepad) and edit it. Save locally and double clik on it.

Comment: but every time I start this web start app., it checks  and downloads this JNLP file.

Comment: the jnlp file already has similar entry, please check the Edit 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by j2se version tag under resources

```
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.5" />
    <jar href="Test.jar" download="eager" />
</resources>
```

Following are more attributes it will help you

Tag Name:java (or j2se)

Specifies what version(s) of Java to run the application with.

**version**
Describes an ordered list of version ranges to use.

**href**
The URL denoting the supplier of this version of java, and where it may be downloaded from.

Stolen from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html)

Comment: the jnlp file already has similar entry, please check the Edit 2.